# Alternate Mirror to Download the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I am in urgent need of Linux kernel 2.6.35.7 but kernel.org is down from past 10 days I am unable to get it from anywahere. Can Some one please suggest from where I can download it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try a Google search, like "linux kernel mirror" ?

Comment: It doesn't matter frome where do you download the kernel, but be sure to check it's GPG signature.

Comment: kernel.org is back now, so I guess this question can be retired.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one from Indonesia: http://kambing.ui.ac.id/linux/